# Concatenar varios txt que están dentro de una carpeta y hacer un solo archivo

Tags: c#, archivo

Quiero concatenar varios archivos txt o planos y hacer un solo archivo, lo que necesito saber es si hay una forma de reducir el código, usar como expresiones lambda, actualmente mi código está así:

```
void concArchivos(string rutaArchivos)
{
    string ruta = Path.GetDirectoryName(rutaArchivos);
    string[] lista = Directory.GetFiles(ruta);            
    List<String> listArchivos = new List<string>();           

    foreach (string archivo in lista)
    {
        string[] renglones = File.ReadAllLines(archivo);

        foreach (string registro in renglones)               
            listArchivos.Add(registro);                
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(rutaArchivos + ".con", listArchivos);
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Yo no veo nada malo en ese codigo, cual seria el problema?

Comment: Hacerlo con una expresión lamda o algo asi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Otra alternativa, basada en la respuesta de Japv, usando un foreach in-line con lambda

```
    void concArchivos(string rutaArchivos)
    {
        string ruta = Path.GetDirectoryName(rutaArchivos);
        var lista = Directory.GetFiles(ruta).ToList();
        string rutaFinal = rutaArchivos + ".con";

        lista.ForEach(file => File.AppendAllLines(rutaFinal, File.ReadAllLines(file)));
    }
```

Obs: Debes agregar el using correspondiente using ***System.Linq;***

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo te agradezco

Answer (score 5):

Podrias usar un .ToList() para convertir el arreglo de string "lista" a una lista de string y de esta manera puedes usar todo el poder de Linq, el código te quedaría de las siguiente manera:

```
    public void GetConcArchivos(string rutaArchivos)
    {
        var ruta = Path.GetDirectoryName(rutaArchivos);
        var lista = Directory.GetFiles(ruta).ToList();            
        var listArchivos = lista.SelectMany(File.ReadAllLines).ToList();

        File.WriteAllLines(rutaArchivos + ".con", listArchivos);
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5):

```
void concArchivos(string rutaArchivos)
{
   string ruta = Path.GetDirectoryName(rutaArchivos);
   string[] lista = Directory.GetFiles(ruta); 
   string rutaFinal = rutaArchivos + ".con";
   string[] renglones;           

   foreach (string archivo in lista)
   {
      renglones = File.ReadAllLines(archivo);
      File.AppendAllLines(rutaFinal, renglones );
   }
}
```

Con esta solución usarías solamente un **ciclo foreach**. Vas recorriendo cada archivo y leyendo todas sus líneas con el **método ReadAllLine** de la **clase File**, y posteriormente usarías el **método AppendAllLines** para añadir al final del archivo el nuevo contenido, de esta forma no sobrescribes el fichero.

La declaración de la **variable renglones** la saco del **ciclo foreach**, ya que si está dentro se construiría la variable tantas veces como iteraciones hubiese.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo